# Why did Diana compare Themyscira to a coffee cup?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman-1984

Diana speaks to Steve:

> Diana: It was just a **coffee cup**...and I lost it.

Why did Diana compare Themyscira to a coffee cup?

Comment: It's not clear that she did, unless you can provide a relevant quote or reference. She was after all talking about trying to make the jet aircraft that they were in invisible - not her home.

Comment: Downvotes seem really harsh: This is someone suffering from a misunderstanding. It is quite easy to understand something if you already understand it. I am glad @FuzzyBoots provided such a clear and welcoming answer to a new user. Welcome to SFF.SE Randy Root. J!

Comment: @Lexible Premise is false. Title should be reworded to not be misleading.

Comment: @Mithoron You haven't been "mislead," this is someone not making a connection, and misunderstanding something which got spelled out in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short, she doesn't. She's describing the process of making something invisible, something that her father did with Themyscira, and she's stating that she's only done that process once, with a coffee cup.

> **Diana**: My father hid Themyscira from the world, and I’ve been trying to learn how he did it.
>
> **Steve**: Did what?
>
> **Diana**: Made something invisible.
> But in 50 years, I’ve only done it once.
>
> **Steve**: Well, now’s not a bad time to start trying.
> How long does it last?
>
> **Diana**: I don’t know.
> It was just a coffee cup… and I lost it.